# UITableView crashes with static accessory views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, static

### Background

I have a `UITableView` full of cells with accessory views. To improve scrolling performance, I have declared the accessory views as static. For example, in my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSString* identifier = @"Identifier";

UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if(!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:identifier];
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
cell.accessoryView = nil;

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0: {
        static UISegmentedControl* control;
        if(!control) {
            control = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[...];
        }

        [control removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];

        // ...
        // setup
        // ...
        break;
    }

    case 1: {
        static UISegmentedControl* control;
        if(!control) {
            control = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[...]];
        }

        [control removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];

        // ...
        // setup
        // ...
        break;
    }

    case 2: {
        static UISwitch* s;
        if(!s) {
            s = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
        }

        [s removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];

        // ...
        // setup
        // ...
        break;
    }

    case 3: {
        static UISwitch* s;
        if(!s) {
            s = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
        }

        [s removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];

        // ...
        // setup
        // ...
        break;
    }         
}
```

et cetera. The table have 4 sections similar to this. In one of them, changing the values of the controls requires updating other cells, which is done by calling `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation`.

### The Problem

Everything works great **except** if the switches/controls are toggled quickly, at which point the app freezes (but *doesn't crash*). The app then displays high CPU usage and high Energy Impact in the debugger, and ultimately closes after 20 seconds or so.

### Experimentation

I have found that if I simply remove the static keyword from the declarations (so that the views are reallocated each time), this crash doesn't occur, but scrolling performance is a bit choppy, which I'd like to avoid.

Interestingly, reloading the cells with `-reloadSections:withRowAnimation` causing a freeze immediately (on the first toggle).

Reloading the entire table with `-reloadData` causes no problem at all. This might suggest there is some issue with the table view's internal animation.

### Question

Why is the use of static accessory views causing crashes when the cells are reloaded multiple times quickly (or immediately with `-reloadSections:`)?

Comment: For better *performance* you might design the cells in Interface Builder rather than in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It's pretty convenient to create multiple different prototype cells and reuse them.